# What kind of book keeping does the OS do when we use new to allocate memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

Besides remembering the address of the pointer of the object, I think the OS also need to record how large the size of the memory is. So that when we use `delete`, the os will know how much memory to free.

Can anyone tell me more details about this? What other information are recorded? And where are those information stored? What does the OS do after you delete the memory?

Comment: Which OS? Also, `new` is alibrary-specific thing on top of OS facilities. Please make sure to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted, `new` is a library function, not an OS feature.

The general case is approximately like this:

- The C++ compiler translates the `new` keyword into function calls to `malloc()` (or equivalent)
- The allocator keeps a list of free blocks of memory, it searches there for the best match.
- Typically, the 'best' match is bigger than the amount asked by your program.  if so, the allocator splits the block, marks one with the size (and maybe a few other metadata), puts the rest back into the free list, and returns the allocated block to the your program.
- If no appropriate free block is found, the allocator asks for some chunk of memory from the OS.  There are several ways to do it, but it's typically considered a slow operation, so it asks in bigger steps (at least one page at a time, usually 4KB).  When it gets the new free block, splits into the requested size and the rest is put in the free list.
- The OS is the one controlling the MMU (Memory Management Unit) of the processor.  This unit is the one that translates the linear addresses as seen by the currently running process into the physical addresses of RAM pages.  This allows the OS the flexibility it needs to allocate and deallocate RAM pages to each process.
- Each process has a different memory map, that allows each one to 'see' a linear memory space while at the same time keeping each process isolated from the others.  The OS is the one who loads and unloads the map into the MMU at each process switch.  Allocating a new page to a process ultimately means adding it to the memory map of the process.

Answer (score 0):

> can anyone tell me more detail about this?

These are all details that are highly dependent on the OS and compiler and I can only provide fairly broad answers (but you really shouldn't have to worry about this, unless you are thinking of going into that line of work, of course).

> what other information are recorded?

Generally, freestore memory is commonly referred to as the "heap". This is basically because it is implemented as a heap, which is a priority-queue implementation that builds a tree of nodes (blocks of free memory). The actual implementation and the algorithms used are very complex because they need to perform very well (i.e. free blocks need to be found very quickly when requesting new memory, and newly freed memory has to be merged to the heap very quickly as well) and then, there are all the fragmentation issues and so on. Look at the wiki on [Buddy memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation) for a very simplified version.

So, there is quite a bit more than just the list of allocated pointers and their corresponding memory-block sizes. In fact, the list of available memory blocks is far more important.

> and where are those information stored?

The Heap is a part of the running program (in fact, each process, and even each loaded module, will have one or more such structures). The heap is not residing in the OS (and I'm not even sure it needs to even be given by the OS, at least not for all OSes). However, the heap obviously asks the OS to provide it with large blocks of memory that it can incorporate into its tree of free memory-blocks, whenever capacity is exhausted by the memory requests of your program.

> what does the OS do after you delete the memory?

Generally, when you delete memory, it simply gets added to the list of free (or available) memory blocks, and possibly gets merged with adjacent free memory-blocks if present. There is no "filling the memory with zeros" or any other actual operation on the memory that gets done, that is unnecessary and a waste of processing time.